# Consumer present in different server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running my kafka producer in a server X and i want to consume the messages from an another server Y. While doing this i am getting an exception . Do I need to any setting or whitelisting in a properties file in order to allow consumer from outside IPs to consume the messages?

When I am running the consumer in same server, it is not giving any error.

Comment: "While doing this i am getting an exception" -> *what* exception? You need to help us to help you :)

Comment: Please share your `server.properties` file

Comment: I came to know that listener to be mentioned in server.properties file. Can you please tell me what should be the value? Server.properties file is as below:
############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092